# Slim route mapping functions to classes

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

In fatfree framework,the route can do such things instead of writing lines of codes in callback function

```
$f3->route('GET /about','WebPage->display');
```

Where WebPage->display is class method and the class will be instanced before the method is invoked,I'm thinking of ways to do the same in slim  framework but I don't have a clue while reading their doc on their official website,can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, as of the time of writing there is still nothing I can find in the docs about mapping routes to classes in the Slim Framework.

But the functionality *does* exist, since version [2.4.0](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/releases/tag/2.4.0) (November 2013). It's called "Class Controllers".

The link above provides a simple example, but I will provide one as well.

You can use classes as controller class instances, as callbacks for your Slim app routes (and their parameters):

```
$app->get('/user/:id/', '\User:find');
```

This will call the `find` method of the `User` class and pass the value if the `:id` parameter as the first parameter to the `find` method. So your callback class might look something like this:

```
class User {
    public function find($theId) {
        // Do something with $theId...
    }
}
```

It is unfortunate that this useful Slim Framework feature has not found its way to the official documentation (yet).

Comment: It doesn't seem to show up in the "related links", but I found more information about Class Controllers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776707/slim-framework-routes-and-controlers