# Slim Framework: routes and controllers

Tags: php, slim

Originally, my Slim Framework app had the classic structure

(index.php)

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});
$app->run();
```

But as I added more routes and groups of routes, I moved to a controller based approach:

index.php

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello/:name', 'HelloController::hello');
$app->run();
```

HelloController.php

```
<?php
class HelloController {
    public static function hello($name) {
        echo "Hello, $name";
    }
}
```

This works, and it had been helpful to organize my app structure, while at the same time lets me build unit tests for each controler method.

However, I'm not sure this is the right way. I feel like I'm mocking Silex's `mount` method on a sui generis basis, and that can't be good. Using the $app context inside each Controller method requires me to use \Slim\Slim::getInstance(), which seems less efficient than just using $app like a closure can.

So... is there a solution allowing for both efficiency and order, or does efficiency come at the cost of route/closure nightmare?

Comment: Seems like the way to go would be to use the DI and/or Middleware to add an extra routing layer. You would assign something of a generic closure/middleware to each route and then let it process which controller to instantiate and which method to invoke. Seems like i did this once before but i cant find the project. If i can get a POC working relatively quickly I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I'd appreciate that :). BTW, I spent a couple of hours looking at [fortrabbit/slimcontroller](https://github.com/fortrabbit/slimcontroller). It has a lot of lexical sweetness but the important thing happening under the hood is that it uses Slim DI container to instance every controller, passing $app to the constructor. Of course all your controllers must inherit from SlimController\SlimController.

Comment: Hmm, you know that sounds pretty much exactly like what i was rigging up. Is there a reason you passed on that package? (havent looked at the code yet)

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i was thinking but with more features since i was just trying to POC...

Comment: That package doesn't override route convenience methods ($app->get, $app->post). Instead it makes you declare a route array.  That array lets you specify httpverb, route pattern, middleware and Controller:method, but no route groups, no named routes or parameter validation. The Controller:method use a single colon instead of *paamayim nekudotayim*, and they can't be static methods. Whatever the solution I might adopt, I wouldn't like to add so much magic as to render the app difficult for another dev to mantain. I kind of prefer not-so-efficient before too-much-magic to explain to a rookie dev

Comment: I take you point but, I dont think the single colon is an issue thats what Symfony2 and Silex use, and in order to do this you have to have some kind of syntax or convention (syntax is better IMO) ;-) In fact it might be more confusing to use the paamayim nekudotayim because then one might assume that it implies a static invocation of a method. As for lacking support of groups and validation i can see that being problematic, but i dont see the array thing in general being the times I have used Slim (and Silex) the first thing i do is make my routes config file based using either YAML or JSON.

Comment: Personally I'd fork that package and then attempt to add support for the missing features.

Comment: @prodigitalson in the end I only had to extend two classes and, particularly, only one method on each of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess I can share what I did with you guys. I noticed that every route method in Slim\Slim at some point called the method *mapRoute*

(I changed the indentation of the official source code for clarity)

`Slim.php`

```
 protected function mapRoute($args)
    {
        $pattern = array_shift($args);
        $callable = array_pop($args);

        $route = new \Slim\Route(
              $pattern, 
              $callable, 
              $this->settings['routes.case_sensitive']
        );
        $this->router->map($route);
        if (count($args) > 0) {
            $route->setMiddleware($args);
        }

        return $route;
    }
```

In turn, the Slim\Route constructor called *setCallable*

`Route.php`

```
public function setCallable($callable)
{
    $matches = [];
    $app = $this->app;
    if (
         is_string($callable) && 
         preg_match(
           '!^([^\:]+)\:([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)$!', 
           $callable, 
           $matches
         )
       ) {
            $class = $matches[1];
            $method = $matches[2];
            $callable = function () use ($class, $method) {
                static $obj = null;
                if ($obj === null) {
                    $obj = new $class;
                }
                return call_user_func_array([$obj, $method], func_get_args());
            };
        }

        if (!is_callable($callable)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Route callable must be callable');
        }

        $this->callable = $callable;
    }
```

Which is basically

- If `$callable` is a string and (**mind the single colon**) has the format `ClassName`**:**`method` then it's non static, so Slim will instantiate the class and then call the method on it.
- If it's not callable, then throw an exception (reasonable enough)
- Otherwise, whatever it is (ClassName::staticMethod, closure, function name) it will be used as-is.

`ClassName` should be the FQCN, so it's more like `\MyProject\Controllers\ClassName`.

The point where the controller (or whatever) is instantiated was a good opportunity to inject the App instance. So, for starters, I [overrode](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/overrode) *mapRoute* to inject the app instance to it:

`\Util\MySlim`

```
 protected function mapRoute($args)
    {
        $pattern = array_shift($args);
        $callable = array_pop($args);

        $route = new \Util\MyRoute(
            $this, // <-- now my routes have a reference to the App
            $pattern, 
            $callable, 
            $this->settings['routes.case_sensitive']
        );
        $this->router->map($route);
        if (count($args) > 0) {
            $route->setMiddleware($args);
        }

        return $route;
    }
```

So basically `\Util\MyRoute` is `\Slim\Route` with an extra parameter in its constructor that I store as `$this->app`

At this point, *getCallable* can inject the app into every controller that needs to be instantiated

`\Util\MyRoute.php`

```
public function setCallable($callable)
{
    $matches = [];
    $app = $this->app;
    if (
       is_string($callable) && 
       preg_match(
          '!^([^\:]+)\:([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)$!', 
          $callable, 
          $matches
          )
       ) {
        $class = $matches[1];
        $method = $matches[2];

        $callable = function () use ($app, $class, $method) {
            static $obj = null;
            if ($obj === null) {
                $obj = new $class($app); // <--- now they have the App too!!
            }
            return call_user_func_array([$obj, $method], func_get_args());
        };
    }

    if (!is_callable($callable)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Route callable must be callable');
    }

    $this->callable = $callable;
}
```

So there it is. Using this two classes I can have `$app` injected into whatever Controller I declare on the route, as long as I use a single colon to separate controller from method. Using *paamayim nekudotayim* will call the method as static and therefore will throw an error if I try to access `$this->app` inside it.

I ran tests using [blackfire.io](https://blackfire.io/) and... the performance gain is negligible.

**Pros**:

- this saves me the pain of calling *$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()* on every static method call accounting for about 100 lines of text overall.
- it opens the way for further optimization by making every controller inherit from an abstract controller class, which in turn wraps the app methods into convenience methods.
- it made me understand Slim's request and response lifecycle a little better.

**Cons:**

- performance gains are negligible
- you have to convert all your routes to use a single colon instead of paamayin, and all your controller methods from static to dynamic.
- inheritance from Slim base classes might break when they roll out v 3.0.0

**Epilogue**: (4 years later)

In Slim v3 they removed the static accessor. In turn, the controllers are instantiated with the app's container, if you use the same convention `FQCN\ClassName:method`. Also, the method receives the request, response and `$args` from the route. Such DI, much IoC. I like it a lot.

Looking back on my approach for Slim 2, it broke the most basic principle of drop in replacement (Liskov Substitution).

```
class Route extends \Slim\Route
{
  protected $app;
  public function __construct($app, $pattern, $callable, $caseSensitive = true) {
   ...
   }
}
```

It should have been

```
class Route extends \Slim\Route
{
  protected $app;
  public function __construct($pattern, $callable, $caseSensitive = true, $app = null) {
   ...
   }
}
```

So it wouldn't break the contract and could be used transparently.